# Why is original array modified from another method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am given these 2 methods and when i run question8 it prints out "1 3" but I don't understand why. Shouldn't the doSomething method not affect the "arr" array in the question8 method and therefore print out "2 4"

```
private static void question8() {
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
    doSomething(arr);
    System.out.print(arr[1] + " ");
    System.out.print(arr[3]);
}
private static void doSomething(int[] list) {
    int[] b = list;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make the questions title more meaningful?

Comment: Is that better? @Mr.Alien
Let me know :)

Comment: @user1702529 Much better :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array is an `Object`, The reference variable is passed by value. Same object is accessed. In your code,

```
private static void doSomething(int[] list) {
int[] b = list; // this means list and b are referring to the same array that was being referenced by list reference variable
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = i;
  }
}
```

This is how it goes

- You create the array in `question8()` method.
- You are passing it to `doSomething()` method from `question8()`
- The same array object is passed to `doSomething()` method which is being referred by `arr` variable in `question8()` method.
- Now again, you are doing `int[] b = list` which means variable `b` is referring to the array object that is being referred by variable `list`. Again the array object is same.

To understand this thing properly you can read about [pass by value in java with primitives and reference variables](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/24/pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/). The reference variable part is useful for you.

Comment: I thought all parameters were passed by value in java so the method just receives a separate copy of whatever data was passed to it. So if that is true, why does the the method doSomething alter the original arr array even though it only uses a copy of it?
@Prasad Kharkar

Comment: @user1702529: parameters are indeed passed by value. But what is passed is not an object or an array, but a *reference to an object* or a *reference to an array*. If you assign another array to the list argument, the variable in the main method won't be affected.

Comment: @user1702529. What you know is true. Whatever data is passed to the method is copied. Only difference is that whole array is not being passed. Only the reference variable that refers to array objects is copied into another method. Hence referring the same array object.

Comment: OHH okay. So when I pass an object as a parameter, it passes a copy of the reference of the original object i passed, thus any changes i make in the method are also changing the original object.
Yet if i pass a primitive as a parameter such as int or double then the method receives a copy of the actual content, not a reference to the original primitive, thus any changes made to the primitive in the supplementary method wont affect the original primitive
Is this correct? @PrasadKharkar, JBNizet

Comment: @user1702529, yes sir.

Comment: and lastly can you give me an example with code of the doSomething method in which, as you said " the variable in the main method won't be affected"
would it look like this
int b = new int[list.length]
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = list[i]
}
@JBNizet

Comment: or @PrasadKharkar could you confirm that last bit of code i typed for me?